# Alignment of list environments

Tags: lists, vertical-alignment

I am seeming to have troubles with two environments dealing with lists. The two are

```
\begin{description}           \begin{problemlist}
  .....                         ......
\end{description}              \end{problemlist}
```

The trouble is that the text with the body of the document will not align properly, as it will with other list environments such as

```
\begin{enumerate}           \begin{itemize}
  .....                         ......
\end{enumerate}              \end{itemize}
```

A mwe is provided below:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\oddsidemargin=0pt
\topmargin=1pt
\evensidemargin=0pt
\headheight=15pt
\headsep=15pt
\textwidth=6.2truein
\marginparsep=0pt
\textheight=8.75truein

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
\item[Problem 1.] The sky is a very nice blue color. The sky is a very nice
blue color. The sky is a very nice blue color. The sky is a very nice blue color. The 
sky is a very nice blue color. The sky is a very nice blue color. The sky is a very  
nice blue color. The sky is a very nice blue color. The sky is a very nice blue color. 
The sky is a very nice blue color. The sky is a very nice blue color. The sky is a very 
nice blue color. The sky is a very nice blue color. The sky is a very nice blue color. 
The sky is a very nice blue color.

\bigskip

\hspace{1.4cm} \textbf{\underline{Solution:}}

\vspace{0.15in}

\hspace{1.42cm} 
The sky is a very nice blue color. The sky is a very nice blue color. The sky is a very  
nice blue color. The sky is a very nice blue color. The sky is a very nice blue color. 
The sky is a very nice blue color. The sky is a very nice blue color. The sky is a very 
nice blue color. The sky is a very nice blue color. The sky is a very nice blue color. 
The sky is a very nice blue color. The sky is a very nice blue color. The sky is a very 
nice blue color. The sky is a very nice blue color. The sky is a very nice blue color.
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

You will see that the sentences after the very first sentence in each paragraph does not stay aligned with the with the first one. When changing the environment to `enumerate` or `itemize` you will see the automatic alignment.

Is there a  fix for this of some kind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the package `enumitem` It is more comfortable as `enumerate` and has more features.

You should also use the package `geometry` instead of the manual manipulation of the lengths.

**EDIT 1:** Use `geometry`

**EDIT 2:** I expand the example with `newlist` and `setlist`. Now you can use the environment `problemdescript`.

****EDIT 3:** See comments -- I Changed the format of the label to "**Problem** 1".

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{textwidth=6.2truein,textheight=8.75truein}
\geometry{showframe}
\pagestyle{empty}

\newlist{problemdescript}{enumerate}{1}
%\setlist[problemdescript]{font=\sffamily\bfseries,label={Problem~\arabic*.},leftmargin=2.5cm}
\setlist[problemdescript]{label={\textbf{Problem}~\arabic*.},leftmargin=2.5cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{problemdescript}
\item The sky is a very nice blue color. The sky is a very nice
blue color. The sky is a very nice blue color. The sky is a very nice blue color. The 
sky is a very nice blue color. The sky is a very nice blue color. The sky is a very  
nice blue color. The sky is a very nice blue color. The sky is a very nice blue color. 
The sky is a very nice blue color. The sky is a very nice blue color. The sky is a very 
nice blue color. The sky is a very nice blue color. The sky is a very nice blue color. 
The sky is a very nice blue color.

\bigskip

\hspace{1.4cm} \textbf{\underline{Solution:}}

\vspace{0.15in}

\hspace{1.42cm} 
The sky is a very nice blue color. The sky is a very nice blue color. The sky is a very  
nice blue color. The sky is a very nice blue color. The sky is a very nice blue color. 
The sky is a very nice blue color. The sky is a very nice blue color. The sky is a very 
nice blue color. The sky is a very nice blue color. The sky is a very nice blue color. 
The sky is a very nice blue color. The sky is a very nice blue color. The sky is a very 
nice blue color. The sky is a very nice blue color. The sky is a very nice blue color.
\end{problemdescript}


\begin{description}[font=\sffamily\bfseries,leftmargin=2.5cm,style=sameline]
\item[Problem 1.] The sky is a very nice blue color. The sky is a very nice
blue color. The sky is a very nice blue color. The sky is a very nice blue color. The 
sky is a very nice blue color. The sky is a very nice blue color. The sky is a very  
nice blue color. The sky is a very nice blue color. The sky is a very nice blue color. 
The sky is a very nice blue color. The sky is a very nice blue color. The sky is a very 
nice blue color. The sky is a very nice blue color. The sky is a very nice blue color. 
The sky is a very nice blue color.

\bigskip

\hspace{1.4cm} \textbf{\underline{Solution:}}

\vspace{0.15in}

\hspace{1.42cm} 
The sky is a very nice blue color. The sky is a very nice blue color. The sky is a very  
nice blue color. The sky is a very nice blue color. The sky is a very nice blue color. 
The sky is a very nice blue color. The sky is a very nice blue color. The sky is a very 
nice blue color. The sky is a very nice blue color. The sky is a very nice blue color. 
The sky is a very nice blue color. The sky is a very nice blue color. The sky is a very 
nice blue color. The sky is a very nice blue color. The sky is a very nice blue color.
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @nightowl let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1076/discussion-between-marco-and-night-owl)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package instead of the `enumerate` package. It offers many ways for customizing margins and alignment. With `enumitem` you can create your own self-designed lists. Check out the [documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for that info. How could one actually do it using the above environments, or is it too hard? :)

Comment: @night owl:You can customize above environments simply by options such as Marco showed `\begin{description}[leftmargin=2.5cm,style=sameline] ...` or by `\setdescription` or `\setlist`. The only hard issue is reading the manual, to which I put a link.